# How to write .child:not(:last-child):hover > img in Tailwind

Tags: tailwind-css

I am trying to write `.child:not(:last-child):hover > img { transform: translateX(-10px); }` in Tailwind. Couldn't find anything similar in the docs.
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/BekzodIsakov/pen/mdzmBXM?editors=1100)

I looked at **group** label but the documentation doesn't provide any tips similar to what I am trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for arbitrary values, specifically this selector: `hover:[&>*:not(:last-child)]:translate-x-[10px]`. What it does is on hover, select all children `[&>*]`, except for the last `:not(:last-child)`, and apply a tailwind class to these children `:translate-x-[10px]`.

For more information regarding this I would recommend looking into [arbitrary values and selectors](https://v2.tailwindcss.com/docs/just-in-time-mode).

*Note I did not take over the exact styling of your example in the code snippet, just an idea of how it would work.*

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<h1>Using arbitrary values</h1>
<div class="parent flex hover:[&>*:not(:last-child)]:translate-x-[10px]">
  <div class='child -mr-[10px]'><img src="https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe&size=80" class="rounded-[50%] shadow-lg" alt=""></div>
  <div class='child -mr-[10px]'><img src="https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe&size=80" class="rounded-[50%] shadow-lg" alt=""></div>
  <div class='child -mr-[10px]'><img src="https://eu.ui-avatars.com/api/?name=John+Doe&size=80" class="rounded-[50%] shadow-lg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution with arbitrary values is working. But the one with group label is inaccurate. Can you edit it to behave like the other solution or remove it in order to avoid possible confusion for others?

Comment: The group label doesn't give the desired result, it was more meant as an example of how a group label works since it was mentioned in the question. So I removed it from the answer to avoid confusion!